# Set Twin.Desired BindingException cannot convert JObject to TwinCollection

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-iot-hub

I've created a wrapper around IoT device twin desired properties on the server side that looks like this:

```
 public class Desired
    {
        private readonly Twin twin;

        public Desired(Twin twin)
        {
            this.twin = twin;
        }

        public Config Config
        {
            get
            {
                if (this.twin.Properties.Desired.Contains(ConfigProperty))
                {
                    TwinCollection config = this.twin.Properties.Desired[ConfigProperty]; 
                    // read the settings, evaluate, construct config
                    return result;
                }

                return null;
            }

            set
            {
                var result = new TwinCollection();
                result[nameof(Config.Name)] = value.Name;
                // Set other stuff

                this.twin.Properties.Desired[ConfigProperty] = result;
            }
        }
}
```

This works really well for my purposes with one exception. If I read the twin from IoT hub, wrap it into Desired, and write the Config property (when it does not yet exist in the JSON structure on the IoT hub side, i.e. writing it for the first time), than I cannot read it anymore without saving the twin in between. So sth like this:

```
var twin = await this.registryManager.GetTwinAsync(serial);
var desired = new Desired(twin);
desired.Config = new Config(...);
var readOut = desired.Config; // THROWS AT LINE TwinCollection config = this.twin.Properties.Desired[ConfigProperty];
```

I see in the debugger that Config property is there with the right values. But if I try to read it immideatelly, I get a BindingException: Cannot convert JObject to TwinCollection.
If I save the twin in between, than it can be read out without a problem.

Indeed in the debugger if I query the type of this.twin.Properties.Desired[ConfigProperty] it's JObject! How can this be? In the setter I'm passing a TwinCollection, so where is the type information gets changed?

Comment: did you find what was the reason?

Comment: it was long ago.. I guess I did not. I looked in the code, and I use there a copy of the read out twin for saving: var twinPatch = new Desired(new Twin(twin.DeviceId) { ETag = twin.ETag, Version = twin.Version, }); than modify the patch twinPatch.Config = config; and save it. So basically did not work for me with the same object. As it's only in one place in my code, didn't give it much more thought.